# Removing oily film

Tags: head-retention, bubble

On my last homebrew when I transferred my beer to a bucket for bottling I noticed that the top had an oily shimmer to it. When I tried the beer a few weeks later the beer came out with pretty weak head and not enough bubbly. How do I remove that oily shimmer before bottling next time? Did it cause my problems, or was that something else.

Comment: can you give more details please - the oily film may not be the cause of the problems if there was little carbonation also

Comment: What specifically would you need to know. It was a partial grain dunkelwiezen. It fermented for about 3 weeks and was bottle conditioned for 3 weeks. The oily film was very light and had a slight rainbow shimmer to it.

Comment: You didn't by chance boil your grains did you?

Comment: Steeped them at 155 degrees F. It might have gotten a little hotter than that, but not boiling.

Comment: Can you post up the recipe? Perhaps you had some unconventional additions in the boil or something in left field.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7wrhbPVrjZUcWhDR0RYNTVNZVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There's nothing in the recipe that would hint towards any sort of oily appearance.  I assume you didn't deviate from the recipe's steps, or have any moments during the brew day where you found yourself saying "oops"?  You didn't happen to use extract, grains or hops that you found in a tucked away box in your grandfather's old house or anything metaphorically similar?

Comment: Did you use ferm cap or any other additive? Whenni use fermcap i get a residue buts its expected as it L's purpose is to break surface tension. Could it be left over cleaning solution on the inside of you bucket or carboy?

Comment: I did not use deviate from the recipe. What is written in that document are the steps I actually took on brewday. I did not use any fermcap or other additive. It could possibly be the Star Sans solution I used, but I made the solution the same way I also do (1oz to 5 gallons) and I have never seen this before.

Comment: Actually, something occurred to me yesterday while brewing.  What do you use to clean & sanitize your buckets/kettles/etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, its highly possible that the oily surface you observed **is not at all related to your head and carbonation problems**.

I've seen that oily 'shimmer' on the top of several beers in primary, and like you, I was worried that some soap or something had gotten in there. However, I never noticed a correlation between the oily/rainbow sheen and any head problems.

I don't know what causes that little oil slick on top of the primary, but it could just be oils from the hops or something. Perhaps an adjunct like oats can add it too, who knows? Anyway, I would just make sure next time that you rinse all your gear real well to make sure there's no cleanser left behind, but don't freak out about it too much.

Comment: I agree - 36 hours carbonating at 30psi and then the remainder of the week at 13psi didn't seem like enough time to me to force carbonate, and that is more likely the problem.

Comment: 30? 13? what units are you talking about

Comment: PSI.  30 PSI for the first 36 hours, and then 13 (or whatever your serving PSI is) PSI.  I've had good success with this.

Comment: @anton2g I was quoting from your recipe

Comment: @Scott, I also use that schedule for kegged beers and it works pretty well for most beers, but maybe not ones that need those high, "prickly" levels of carbonation.